# Joomla 3 Smart Search List Non Search Articles

Tags: search, smartsearch

I am a wee bit confused with the results from a Smart Search search. The site ahs about 50 articles, search for a specific term which there are approx. 10 articles that have that search item.

example search query demo

the result lists the first page correct, the 2nd page is a list of all non search article AND 3rd page has a combo of both some non search article and correct search articles

My question why is Smart Search displaying articles that do not have that specific search query word?

Comment: Does the issue persist if you go to Smart Search component and re-index?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that several times and the results are the same. Smart Search index correctly and it appears that shows the full index list of articles with and without highlighted search query words.

Comment: Is the search through module or menu item?  Do you have it set to a fixed number of results?

Answer (score 1):

First thank you for responding, @YellowWebMonkey; I did find the problem.

For each article, I had to add optional meta keywords. I had to create a standard list and added the list to each article even though some meta keyword are not in the main body of the article.

I've corrected this oversite on my part and the issue is resolved.

Comment: It seems this solution resolves your issue.  Please mark this page as resolved by awarding your answer the big green tick so that the system stops bumping this page to the top of the question list.